# Android GPS Permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android

As we know in Marshmallow we need to ask permission from users.
Recently I have installed BookMyShow and found there is no dialog pop up for permission.
When I checked from setting->app, All required permissions were there.
how do they do it? ..

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1):

Their `targetSdkVersion` is lower than 23, presumably.

Comment: This is correct. Developers are not required to mode to the new method until their app's `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or greater.